# TWRP recovery logo blinks in nexus 9

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, fastboot, twrp, nexus-9

I have an unlocked nexus 9 (WiFi version) on which I upgraded to android N. Now I want to have a root access on it. I tried to flash twrp recovery 3.0.2 using fastboot,

`fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.2-0-flounder.img`

but then when I try to get to recovery mode I see the logo of TWRP blinking again and again but can't access recovery mode. I tried flashing version 2.8 but then the device is encrypted and I don't want to wipe it.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a version that's not compatible with N. Support for N just released yesterday (local time), get it while it's hot: [dl.twrp.me](https://dl.twrp.me/flounder/)